# JQuery/Angular and .NET API

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs

This might be a very simple question, but i've been trying for about 4 hours now and can't seem to figure it out.

I'm trying to learn some Javascript, so I build a little word game with the use of Jquery and after that I made the same game using Angular. Both the games work the same and to remove duplicate code I made an API with ASP.NET. The API has three GETs;

One for checking if a word is valid(takes a string/returns a
   Boolean).

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Word")]
public Boolean checkWord(String word){..}
```

One to create a board for the game (returns an array of strings).

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Score")]
public int updateScore(String word){..}
```

One to score a word(takes a string/returns an int)

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Board")]
public string[] createBoard()
```

So now I'm trying to connect these two games to the API. The API is just running locally on my pc at the moment. Now in the Jquery game I made a function like this;

```
function getBoard() {
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          board.push(item);
        });
    });
    alert("Data: " + board);
}
```

This was used in the 'Getting started with ASP.NET web API' and if I do a request like this the API gets the request, yet the data object is always empty. Every variation on the above code I tried just keeps failing.

If I type the URI in my browser, it does give me the right response and doesn't fail.

It seems like a very simple problem but my knowledge of Javascript/Jquery/Angular is very limited at the moment and I can't seem te figure it out on my own.

I hope you guys can help me out here.

Comment: I think it is because you are using `getJSON` method and it expects a JSON object in response from the API. But you are not returning a JSON encoded response. Try using `$.ajax` instead. Documentation: [http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Please update your post to include the output from your HTTP calls. Check the network tab of your browser's developer tools to see this information.

Comment: Also consider using Angular's [http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) method: `$http.get(uri, config).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // on success
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
// on error  });`